# On the newsletters page the "show N more [category] sites" is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

On the newsletters page the "show N more [category] sites" is not working. I click on it and the blue bar with that text goes away but it does not show the rest of the choices. I am using IE9 on a Win7 box.

[image]

The error is:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Mon, 5 Sep 2011 16:26:37 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 7173
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/Js/newsletters.js?v=08b9a92c2f42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to repro this in IE9 with compatibility mode turned on. It's fixed now.

A variable declaration in newsletters.js was missing a `var`. In IE, this caused a conflict with an [implicit global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226003/jquery-remote-validation/2226149#2226149). For example, this throws an error in IE7/IE8:

```
<input type="hidden" name="v" value="foo" />
<script>v = 'bar';</script>
```